# What does Data::Util::modify_subroutine do for "around"?

Tags: perl

I can only understand what it does in `before`/`after` cases,

what does it do for `around`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be doing something like [`Sub::Curry`](http://search.cpan.org/~lodin/Sub-Curry-0.8/lib/Sub/Curry.pm) according to the implementation:

```
static SV*
my_build_around_code(pTHX_ SV* code_ref, AV* const around){
    I32 i;
    for(i = av_len(around); i >= 0; i--){
        CV* current;
        MAGIC* mg;
        SV* const sv = validate(*av_fetch(around, i, TRUE), T_CV);
        AV* const params       = newAV();
        AV* const placeholders = newAV();

        av_store(params, 0, newSVsv(sv));       /* base proc */
        av_store(params, 1, newSVsv(code_ref)); /* first argument (next proc) */
        av_store(params, 2, &PL_sv_undef);      /* placeholder hole */

        av_store(placeholders, 2, (SV*)PL_defgv); // *_
        SvREFCNT_inc_simple_void_NN(PL_defgv);

        current = newXS(NULL /* anonymous */, XS_Data__Util_curried, __FILE__);
        mg = sv_magicext((SV*)current, (SV*)params, PERL_MAGIC_ext, &curried_vtbl, (const char*)placeholders, HEf_SVKEY);

        SvREFCNT_dec(params);       /* because: refcnt++ in sv_magicext() */
        SvREFCNT_dec(placeholders); /* because: refcnt++ in sv_magicext() */

        CvXSUBANY(current).any_ptr = (void*)mg;

        code_ref = newRV_noinc((SV*)current);
        sv_2mortal(code_ref);
    }
    return newSVsv(code_ref);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `around` is like a `before` **and** `after`

---

From the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Util):

> Optional arguments:
>
> `before => [subroutine(s)]` called before subr.
>
> `around => [subroutine(s)]` called around subr.
>
> `after => [subroutine(s)]` called after subr.

Comment: It seems the document has no hint that `around` means `before` and `after`